# JavaFX SimpleObjectProperty<T> vs SimpleTProperty

Tags: javafx, properties, observable

What's the difference between using

**SimpleStringProperty** vs **SimpleObjectProperty < String >** or

**SimpleIntegerProperty** vs **SimpleObjectProperty< Integer >**

Besides returning wrappers and not primitive types?(It can be auto casted anyways)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API adds additional functionality for the specific types. So `ObjectProperty` really just defines the API for "being a property" and can only define functionality common to all possible types. On the other hand, `StringProperty` defines (via its superclass `StringExpression`) methods such as [`concat(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/StringExpression.html#concat-java.lang.Object-) which returns another `ObservableValue<String>` which is the current value concatenated with the provided value. Similarly, `IntegerProperty` defines numeric-specific functionality such as [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/IntegerExpression.html#add-int-), [`divide`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/IntegerExpression.html#divide-long-), etc etc.

So the specific types just add extra functionality to the more general type that is specific to those types. It is just the standard use of inheritance.

(Note though, that `IntegerProperty` does not implement `Property<Integer>`, it implements `Property<Number>`.)