# Why does a TableView's change listener give different results for ObjectProperty<T> vs TProperty columns in JavaFX8?

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8, propertychangelistener

A relative Java newbie question.

I have a TableView with extractors and a `ListChangeListener` added to the underlying ObservableList.

If I have a `StringProperty` column in the data model, the change listener doesn't detect changes if I double-click the cell and then hit ENTER without making any changes.  That's good.

However, if I define the column as `ObjectProperty<String>` and double-click and then hit ENTER, *the change listener always detects changes even when none have been made*.

Why does that happen?  What's the difference between `ObjectProperty<String>` and `StringProperty` from a change listener's point of view?

I've read [Difference between SimpleStringProperty and StringProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060633/difference-between-simplestringproperty-and-stringproperty) and [JavaFX SimpleObjectProperty<T> vs SimpleTProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41638183/javafx-simpleobjectpropertyt-vs-simpletproperty) and think I understand the differences.  But I don't understand why the change listener is giving different results for `TProperty`/`SimpleTProperty` and `ObjectProperty<T>`.

If it helps, here is a MVCE for my somewhat nonsensical case.  I'm actually trying to get a change listener working for `BigDecimal` and `LocalDate` columns and have been stuck on it for 5 days.  If I can understand why the change listener is giving different results, I might be able to get my code working.

I'm using JavaFX8 (JDK1.8.0_181), NetBeans 8.2 and Scene Builder 8.3.

```
package test17;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.DefaultStringConverter;

public class Test17 extends Application {

    private Parent createContent() {

        ObservableList<TestModel> olTestModel = FXCollections.observableArrayList(testmodel -> new Observable[] {
                testmodel.strProperty(),
                testmodel.strObjectProperty()
        });

        olTestModel.add(new TestModel("A", "a"));
        olTestModel.add(new TestModel("B", "b"));

        olTestModel.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends TestModel > c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                    System.out.println("===> wasUpdated() triggered");
                }
            }
        });

        TableView<TestModel> table = new TableView<>();

        TableColumn<TestModel, String> strCol = new TableColumn<>("strCol");
        strCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().strProperty());
        strCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new DefaultStringConverter()));
        strCol.setEditable(true);
        strCol.setPrefWidth(100);
        strCol.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<TestModel, String> t) -> {
                ((TestModel) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setStr(t.getNewValue());
        });

        TableColumn<TestModel, String> strObjectCol = new TableColumn<>("strObjectCol");
        strObjectCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().strObjectProperty());
        strObjectCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new DefaultStringConverter()));
        strObjectCol.setEditable(true);
        strObjectCol.setPrefWidth(100);
        strObjectCol.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<TestModel, String> t) -> {
            ((TestModel) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setStrObject(t.getNewValue());
        });

        table.getColumns().addAll(strCol, strObjectCol);
        table.setItems(olTestModel);
        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table.setEditable(true);

        BorderPane content = new BorderPane(table);
        return content;
    }

    public class TestModel {

        private StringProperty str;
        private ObjectProperty<String> strObject;

        public TestModel(
            String str,
            String strObject
        ) {
            this.str = new SimpleStringProperty(str);
            this.strObject = new SimpleObjectProperty(strObject);
        }

        public String getStr() {
            return this.str.get();
        }

        public void setStr(String str) {
            this.str.set(str);
        }

        public StringProperty strProperty() {
            return this.str;
        }

        public String getStrObject() {
            return this.strObject.get();
        }

        public void setStrObject(String strObject) {
            this.strObject.set(strObject);
        }

        public ObjectProperty<String> strObjectProperty() {
            return this.strObject;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.setTitle("Test");
        stage.setWidth(350);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference can be seen by looking at the source code of `StringPropertyBase` and `ObjectPropertyBase`—specfically, their `set` methods.

#### `StringPropertyBase`

```
@Override
public void set(String newValue) {
    if (isBound()) {
        throw new java.lang.RuntimeException((getBean() != null && getName() != null ?
                getBean().getClass().getSimpleName() + "." + getName() + " : ": "") + "A bound value cannot be set.");
    }
    if ((value == null)? newValue != null : !value.equals(newValue)) {
        value = newValue;
        markInvalid();
    }
}
```

#### `ObjectPropertyBase`

```
@Override
public void set(T newValue) {
    if (isBound()) {
        throw new java.lang.RuntimeException((getBean() != null && getName() != null ?
                getBean().getClass().getSimpleName() + "." + getName() + " : ": "") + "A bound value cannot be set.");
    }
    if (value != newValue) {
        value = newValue;
        markInvalid();
    }
}
```

Notice the difference in how they check if the new value is equal to the old value? The `StringPropertyBase` class checks by using `Object.equals` whereas the `ObjectPropertyBase` class uses reference equality (`==`/`!=`).

I can't answer for certain *why* this difference exists, but I can hazard a guess: An `ObjectProperty` can hold *anything* and therefore there's the potential for `Object.equals` to be expensive; such as when using a `List` or `Set`. When coding `StringPropertyBase` I guess they decided that potential wasn't there, that the semantics of `String` equality was more important, or both. There may be more/better reasons for why they did what they did, but as I was not involved in development I'm not aware of them.

---

Interestingly, if you look at how they handle listeners
(`com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper`) you'll see that they check for equality using `Object.equals`. This equality check only occurs if there are currently `ChangeListener`s registered—probably to support lazy evaluation when there are no `ChangeListener`s.

If the new and old values are `equals` the *`ChangeListener`s* are not notified. This doesn't stop the *`InvalidationListener`s* from being notified, however. Thus, your `ObservableList` will fire an update change because that mechanism is based on `InvalidationListener`s and not `ChangeListener`s.

Here's the relevant source code:

#### `ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent`

```
@Override
protected void fireValueChangedEvent() {
    final InvalidationListener[] curInvalidationList = invalidationListeners;
    final int curInvalidationSize = invalidationSize;
    final ChangeListener<? super T>[] curChangeList = changeListeners;
    final int curChangeSize = changeSize;

    try {
        locked = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < curInvalidationSize; i++) {
            try {
                curInvalidationList[i].invalidated(observable);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Thread.currentThread().getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(Thread.currentThread(), e);
            }
        }
        if (curChangeSize > 0) {
            final T oldValue = currentValue;
            currentValue = observable.getValue();
            final boolean changed = (currentValue == null)? (oldValue != null) : !currentValue.equals(oldValue);
            if (changed) {
                for (int i = 0; i < curChangeSize; i++) {
                    try {
                        curChangeList[i].changed(observable, oldValue, currentValue);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(Thread.currentThread(), e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        locked = false;
    }
}
```

And you can see this behavior in the following code:

```
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ObjectProperty<String> property = new SimpleObjectProperty<>("Hello, World!");
    property.addListener(obs -> System.out.printf("Property invalidated: %s%n", property.get()));
    property.addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> System.out.printf("Property changed: %s -> %s%n", ov, nv));
    property.get(); // ensure valid

    property.set(new String("Hello, World!")); // must not use interned String
    property.set("Goodbye, World!");
  }

}
```

Output:

```
Property invalidated: Hello, World!
Property invalidated: Goodbye, World!
Property changed: Hello, World! -> Goodbye, World!
```

Comment: interesting ... seems to be unspecified whether identity or equality change constitutes a change of the value of an ObservableValue (at least I couldn't find anything) - and the implementations don't specify how they are implemented. Hmmm...

Comment: @Slaw Thanks very much for your explanation.  At least I now understand why I've not been able to get a change listener working for `BigDecimal` and `LocalDate` columns.  My current workaround is to define them as `StringProperty` and handle them in my code but I'll now try and write my own "ObjectProperty<T>" class.  I suspect that's beyond my current Java skills but nothing ventured, nothing gained. Thanks again.

Comment: @kleopatra I couldn't find a clear specification either. I notice, though, that _changes_ seem to be implemented based on `equals` but _invalidation_ seems to be implemented by reference equality—except for `StringPropertyBase`. Maybe a changed reference is an invalidation? It seems to fit with the documentation of `ObservableValue`: "_A change event [...] value has changed. An invalidation event [...] value not valid anymore. This distinction becomes important [...] because for a lazily evaluated value one does not know if an invalid value really has changed until it is recomputed._".

Comment: @GreenZebra May I ask what problems are being caused by extra invalidation events? You may not need to worry about them.

Comment: @Slaw Yes, sure. I'm writing an app for home use that records financial data in a SQLite DB, hence the need for `BigDecimal`s and `ObjectProperty<T>`. When data changes in the TableView, I use the change listener to record the type of change (INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE) and the affected DB rowID (which is in the TableView's model). When the SAVE button is hit, I write the SQL to make the changes by rowID and process them in a single, atomic transaction. If there's a better way of doing all of this, I'd love to know about it. And if I can avoid the invalidation issues, even better!  Thanks.  :-)

Comment: @Slaw PS:  I forgot to say that the invalidation issue is having two impacts:  1) I'm incorrectly recording rowIDs as being updated when they're not, and 2) I don't allow the form to close if there are uncommitted changes, which there aren't, so I'm forced to discard non-existent changes.

Comment: @Slaw I've just kludged around the invalidation issue by doing my own value checks for `BigDecimal`s and `LocalDate`s in my `commitEdit()` method. If the values are equal, I `super.commitEdit` using `getItem()` rather than `item`, in effect committing the original `ObjectProperty<T>` variable (object reference?) back to itself. If the values are not equal, or if `item` is not a `BigDecimal` or `LocalDate`, I use `super.commitEdit(item)`.  The kludge works but does anything strike you as glaringly wrong with the approach?

Comment: @GreenZebra I can't think of any issues regarding your workaround. In fact, it's more elegant/simple than what I was thinking: to keep a map of original values and comparing new values with the mapped ones. Note that, if you want, you can make that behavior `TableColumn` based rather than `TableCell` based if you use `TableColumn.onEditCommit`; you'd have to implement the actual set-the-property-with-the-new-value behavior yourself if you go that route, though.

Comment: @Slaw Terrific, thanks again for your help.  It was invaluable.